# Retrieving array keys from JSON input

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have this array:

```
$json = json_decode('
{"entries":[
{"id": "29","name":"John", "age":"36"},
{"id": "30","name":"Jack", "age":"23"}
]}
');
```

and I am looking for a PHP "for each" loop that would retrieve the key names under `entries`, i.e.:

```
id
name
age
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try it

```
foreach($json->entries as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

In the $key you shall get the key names and in the val you shal get the values

Comment: Hi, I have json file i.e file.json i want to show data in table format tried integrating  here is the code  <?php
$json = file_get_contents("file.json");

$j = json_decode($json);

foreach($j as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}   Here is the error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/new_git/json.php on line 6

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
foreach($json->entries as $record){
    echo $record->id;
    echo $record->name;
    echo $record->age;
}
```

If you pass `true` as the value for the second parameter in the `json_decode` function, you'll be able to use the decoded value as an array.

Comment: This will fetch the actual values. I am looking for the key names. Thanks!

Comment: To do that, you'll need the `$json` object to be an array instead. To do that, you need to supply the second parameter to the `json_decode()` function

Comment: I forgot to add that, you should then use the `$json` object as an array and use the `foreach($json['entries'] as $record){ foreach($record as $key=>$value){...}}`

Comment: I didn't know that field names could be used as properties (+1). Saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

I was not satisfied with other answers so I add my own. I believe the most general approach is:

```
$array = get_object_vars($json->entries[0]);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . "<br>";
}
```

where I used `entries[0]` because you assume that all the elements of the `entries` array have the same keys.

Have a look at the official documentation for `key`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($json->entries[0] AS $key => $name) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mihai. Unfortunately, I am getting this: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the properties of the object using `get_object_vars`:

```
 $keys = array();

 foreach($json->entries as $entry)
   $keys += array_keys(get_object_vars($entry));

 print_r($keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $column_name =[];
    foreach($data as $i){
        foreach($i as $key => $i){
            array_push($column_name, $key);
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Consider adding a bit of explanation. Code only answers are strongly discouraged!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer using arrays rather than objects - passing true to `json_decode` will return an array.

```
$json = '{"entries":[{"id": "29","name":"John", "age":"36"},{"id": "30","name":"Jack", "age":"23"}]}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$entries = $data['entries'];

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $id = $entry['id'];
    $name = $entry['name'];
    $age = $entry['age'];
    printf('%s (ID %d) is %d years old'.PHP_EOL, $name, $id, $age);
}
```

Tested at https://www.tehplayground.com/17zKeQcNUbFwuRjC