# is there a way to only get column name out of this?

Tags: laravel

i want to get column name only if its possible[image]

//item table , column new_values data

```
 {"item_name":"
  Chopstick",
  "item_quantity":"4",
  "item_brand":"d",
  "item_serialno":"3",
  "item_tag":"New",
   "item_categories":"Assets",
   "item_unitcost":"4",
   "item_depriciation":"5",
   "item_location":
   "Not Deployed",
   "user_assign":"None",
   "department":"Not Assigned","id":36}
```

//controller

```
$audits=audits::select('new_values')->get();
```

//Blade

```
   @foreach($audits as $colName => $value)
       {{ $colName }}
   @endforeach
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving array keys from JSON input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914687/retrieving-array-keys-from-json-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are using [Audit model package](https://laravel-auditing.herokuapp.com/docs/4.1) If yes then you can use this

```
@foreach($audits as $audit)
    @foreach($audit->new_values as $colName => $value)
        {{ $colName }}
        // use @dd($aud->new_values, $colName) for see what is value
        // other logic
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: to get item_name do i do this? $colName->item_name ?

Comment: this give me result of 0 1 2 3 4 5 is it because of audit package?

Comment: i did edit my post i try dd($audits=audits::select('new_values')->get()); to check

Comment: @dd($aud->new_values, $colName) show tis result As I edit my code. only uncomment line

Comment: Collection {#783 ▼
  #items: array:15 [▼
    0 => audits {#784 ▶}
    1 => audits {#785 ▶}
    2 => audits {#786 ▶}
    3 => audits {#787 ▶}
    4 => audits {#788 ▶}
    5 => audits {#789 ▶}
    6 => audits {#790 ▶}
    7 => audits {#791 ▶}
    8 => audits {#792 ▶}
    9 => audits {#793 ▶}
    10 => audits {#794 ▶}
    11 => audits {#795 ▶}
    12 => audits {#796 ▶}
    13 => audits {#797 ▶}
    14 => audits {#798 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: same result :( {"item_name":"a","item_quantity":"4","item_brand":"a","item_serialno":"4","item_tag":"4","item_categories":"Assets","item_unitcost":"4","item_depriciation":"1","item_location":"Not Deployed","user_assign":"None","department":"Not Assigned","id":35}  i just want to get column name from this or remove column values

Comment: did edit my code again it shows my controller and blade i did make it simple and clean too

Comment: If you see error use @foreach(json_decode($audit->new_values) as $colName => $value)

Comment: ty so much this works now :))) so grateful to have you answer my question patiently

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = json_decode($aud->new_values);
foreach ($json as $name => $value) {
   // Here you have your $name
}
```